# The DELETE method is not supported for this route, laravel 7, but my method isn´t DELETE

Tags: laravel, methods, routes

I´ve this error:  The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

But i´m not trying to **delete something**

My view

```
{!! BootForm::open(['id'=>'form', 'method' => 'POST','route'=>['declaracionenviar.enviarTodo']]); !!} 

{!! BootForm::checkboxElement('ids[]', ' ', $declaracion->id, '', false, ["class"=>'check i-checks']); !!} 

 {!! Form::submit('Send something',['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); !!}

 {!! BootForm::close() !!}
```

My route

```
Route::post('/declaracionenviar/enviarTodo','DeclaracionEnviarController@enviarTodo')->name('declaracionenviar.enviarTodo');
```

My controller

```
public function enviarTodo(Request $request)
    {
        $ids= $request->get('ids');
        dd($ids);

    }
```

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: I don't know much about this form builder BUT `{!! Form::submit('Send something',['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); !!}` shouldn't that line be `BootForm::submit`? There probably is a @mthod('delete') in the `Form`

Comment: This line {!! Form::submit('Send something',['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); !!} it´s the same that this: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send something</button>

Comment: Pls share your entire view file if you still have this issue.